# Population Allele Frequency

Tags: allele-frequency, population-genetics, brap, dnanexus, biobank

In UK biobank research environment

In GENOMICS tab of UK BRAP, if I type `7:140476600-140480852` coordinate in search bar and the same time after filtering my cohort for this coordinate, in `ALLELE TABLE` I see columns like:

```
Cohort AF Cohort Allele Count Population AF Population Allele Count GnomAD AF
```

[image]

I Googled a lot but no clue where population allele count and frequency come from

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know specifically about the UKBB RAP, however, Population Allele Count is the count of that specific allele genotyped in the population in question. In this case, it most likely refers to the population that your cohort is part of. The population allele frequency is the same thing but noted in terms of frequency, i.e. divided by 2 times the number of genotyped individuals in that population.